# Discard response on EAGAIN

Tags: sockets

I have a client application that repeatedly sends commands over a socket connection to a server and receives corresponding responses. This socket connection has a send/recv timeout set.

If the server is slow to respond for some reason, the client receives EAGAIN. On a timeout, I want the client to ignore that response and proceed with sending the next request.

However, currently when I ignore EAGAIN and send the next request, I receive the response from a previous request.

What is the best way to ignore/discard the response on an EAGAIN?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You have to read it. There is no mechanism to ignore bytes in a TCP byte stream.

Comment: @Seymour You are mistaken. The OP asking how to do something that simply cannot be done. The answer is therefore to say so. No critique or clarification is necessary. If you think you know better, I suggest you post your answer so we can comment, vote, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`EAGAIN` may indicate a timeout elapsed (you also need to handle `EWOULDBLOCK` as well).  If you are using TCP, you **must** read pending data before you can read any subsequent data.  If you get an `EAGAIN` on a read, you have to perform the same read again, using the same parameters.  Just because the server is slow to respond (or the network is slow to deliver the response) does not mean the response will not arrive at all, unless the connection is closed/lost.

If you really want to be able to receive responses out of order, you need to design your communication protocol to support that in the first place.  Give each request a unique ID that is echoed in its response.  Send the request but do not wait for the response to arrive.  That will allow the client to have multiple requests in flight at a time, and allow the server to send back responses in any order.  The client will have to read each response as it arrives (which means you have to do the reading asynchronously, typically using a separate thread or some other parallel signaling mechanism) and match up each response's ID to its original request so you know how to then process it.

Comment: EAGAIN can't be 'erroneous'. What it really suggests is that the response took longer to arrive than the timeout period, which in turn may suggest that the timeout is too short. It should be long enough that any expiry indicates a genuine connection problem.